# MVC StringLength max character count

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ms-word

I've added the `StringLenth` validation attribute on one of my properties, but I seem to get differing character counts if I paste text from MS Word. I have some text, and when I view the character count in word, with spaces, it equals 1,997. However, when I paste that text into the textarea on my site which has a `StringLength` of 2000, I get a validation error.

Is this just down to MS Words formatting, or is this issue down the the `StringLength` attribute. I realise this is a bit of an 'open' question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possibly there are some control characters which you don't see maybe? I used to have them at the values I have copied from Excel cells.

Comment: Same answere as @user3021830. Take your word text and remove all control charaters by copying it to ex: notepad and then paste that content to your text area.